# How to specify window size in milliseconds in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Example that works for one second:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
F.window('timestamp_g_date', "1 second" )
```

What I would like:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
F.window('timestamp_g_date', "500 ms" )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `milliseconds`:

`F.window('timestamp_g_date', "500 milliseconds" )`